# UIActivityViewController twitter length

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

Twitter is restricted to a certain length. Facebook allows a lot longer length.

If the length is too long for twitter the activity window comes up blank.

How can I set the activity items specific to twitter versus Facebook?

I would like to post up to ~200 characters on facebook and limit twitter just enough to post.

Any recommendations is appreciated.

Comment: Same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650787/ios-6-uiactivityviewcontroller-items , which has a good accepted answer.